# Figuring out which indices are selected based on a single value

Tags: mysql, logic

Let's say I have a set of five elements for people to choose from. They are allowed to choose multiple elements.

`['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']`

Is there a way to store a single value so that from that value I can determine which elements they chose? One option I thought of was to store as a binary string. So if they chose `a` and `b` I would store it as `11000`. If someone chose `a`, `b`, and `e`, it would be stored as `11001`. I'm wondering if there was a different method. I couldn't think of the appropriate terms to search online. Thanks.

Comment: Can you tell us what you are actually trying to do? In this example you could simply write the string of the chosen characters in the field, but why is there even the requirement to only use one field?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a binary string, why not use the decimal integer for the binary mask? Or you could use a string or list of characters that were selected. Of course depending on what you're using this for, each representation will have its pros and cons.

Comment: A string was the only way I could keep leading and trailing 0's intact. The elements won't be characters like above, but would be either strings or something else, that I would not be able to represent as single characters.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just encoding it is a binary string, storing it as a string in mysql, and processing it myself.

There is some stuff out there about encoding multiple numbers into one number, but they seem overly complicated. [Example](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/69244/encoding-n-natural-numbers-into-one-and-back).